# Rotating display and keeping aspect ratio & resolution

Tags: hdmi, display

I've got an LG 21:9 (2560x1080) monitor which I've managed to get the pi driving successfully using the settings below in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
hdmi_drive=2
disable_overscan=1

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_timings=2560 1 64 64 96 1080 1 3 10 31 0 0 1 60 0 185580000 8

max_framebuffer_width=2560
max_framebuffer_height=1280
framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1080

gpu_mem=128
arm_freq=800
gpu_freq=275
sdram_freq=500
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=400000000
avoid_pwm_pll=1
```

The issue is, I'd like to put this monitor into portrait mode but adding `display_rotate=3` results in the screen not using the full 2560px "height" and it ends up with black boxes top and bottom (almost as if it were a square monitor).

Swapping around only `hdmi_timings` results in a black screen. Swapping `max_framebuffer_width|height` and `framebuffer_width|height` has no effect regardless if `hdmi_timings` is present or not.

Removing all of the above settings and adding only `display_rotate=3` results in the screen not being output at the correct resolution and the monitor stretches it to fill the full space (not ideal but the best out of all three).

My question is, how would one calculate `hdmi_timings` or is there another way I can get the resolution I want, with the correct aspect ratio (21:9), *and* the correct rotation?

**TV specs**

```
Screen size (inches)            25
Panel Type                      IPS
Aspect Ratio                    21:9
Resolution                      2560 x 1080
Brightness (cd/m2)              250
Contrast Ratio                  5000000:1
Viewing Angle (°)               178 /178 (CR≥10)
Colour Depth (Num of Colours)   8bit, 16.7M(True)
Pixel Pitch (mm)                0.2286 x 0.2286
Colour Gamut                    sRGB 100%
Surface Treatment               Hard Coating(3H), Anti-glare
```

Output of EDID

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tvservice -s
state 0x12000a [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tvservice -d dataFile
Written 256 bytes to dataFile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ edidparser dataFile
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing dataFile...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 67x28 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 standby suspend active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is LG_ULTRAWIDE
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 56-75 Hz, horizontal is 30-90 kHz, max pixel clock is 240 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 2560x1080p hfp:64 hs:64 hbp:96 vfp:3 vs:10 vbp:18 pixel clock:185 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 60 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 2560x1080p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 2560x1080p hfp:64 hs:64 hbp:96 vfp:3 vs:10 vbp:18 pixel clock:185 MHz
HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are A5 4B 80
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 6, 640x480p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 11, 800x600p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 18, 1024x768p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 36, 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x714F 8180 81C0 A9C0 B300 0101 0101 0101 
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 21, 1152x864p @ 75 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 0
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 1
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 85, 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (16:9) in standard timing 2
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 83, 1600x900p @ 60 Hz (16:9) in standard timing 3
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 58, 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 4
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:yes, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:1
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (4)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 720x480p @ 60 Hz (2)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 0x822p hfp:334 hs:84 hbp:-163 vfp:52 vs:24 vbp:-27 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 0 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 0x822p @24 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 0x822p hfp:334 hs:84 hbp:-163 vfp:52 vs:24 vbp:-27 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz (native)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 3, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 20, 1920x1080i @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 18, 720x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 5, 1920x1080i @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 31, 1920x1080p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 5
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no extension fields
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (17) 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 3066472)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 3635592)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 4273832)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (6) 640x480p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 31 MHz has a score of 23040
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (9) 800x600p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 40 MHz has a score of 28800
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (11) 800x600p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 49 MHz has a score of 36000
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz (score 5398248)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (16) 1024x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 65 MHz has a score of 47185
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (18) 1024x768p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 78 MHz has a score of 58982
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 117160
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (20) 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 128680
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (21) 1152x864p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 99649
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (31) 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 232360
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 103643
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (36) 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 135 MHz has a score of 98304
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (58) 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 146 MHz has a score of 130840
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (83) 1600x900p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 111400
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (85) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 80296
HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edid_parser exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Milliways said, display rotation should not affect the HDMI timings in any way, since the display has no way of knowing it is rotated. This is something strictly between your X server and the framebuffer.

I would try to configure the framebuffer rotation via [`xorg.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/fbdev):

```
Section "Device"
    Driver "fbdev"
    Option "rotate" "CW"
EndSection
```

Comment: This worked (with a little bit of tweaking). Thanks so much, I've been desperate to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `display_rotate=3` to use my monitor in portrait mode.

I use the default detected screen resolution.

`display_rotate` does **NOT** change the way the screen image is actually displayed, it only changes the way the framebuffer is filled by the GPU. (It also probably changes how the image reported the monitor is interpreted.)

You seem to be trying to specify screen architecture and micromanage settings. The screen characteristics you list with `tvservice -s` do not seem to agree with your settings.

You also seem to have conflicting ideas about what your monotor does; "LG 21:9 (2560x1080) monitor" vs "framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1080".

You should concentrate on getting a normal screen display with consistent settings before trying rotate.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and indicated above (getting it working normally before trying to rotate) and it works well... the issue comes when trying to rotate

Comment: To clarify: settings above (`/boot/config.txt`) are required to make it display properly in landscape. Simply adding `display_rotate=3` to it doesn't work as expected. Adding _only_ `display_rotate=3`, as again indicated above, doesn't provide correct output either.